# Python Redmine Connection

Tags: python, redmine

I try to connect myself to a Redmine server with a script running on a  windows 7 virtual machine with these few lines, but it fails.

I did run the script on another computer without problems, has someone some ideas about what could block the connection process on a virtual machine?

```
redmine_url = 'https://url'
myapi_key = 'myAPIkey'
ticket_author = 'myMail@server.com'
redmine = Redmine(redmine_url, key=myapi_key, impersonate=ticket_author)
project = redmine.project.get('MyProject')
print('im in project number : ',project.id)
```

Here is the message error

> Requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:HTTPSConnectionPool<host=‘myserver‘,port=443>:Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /URLpath.json?key=myAPIkey&limit=100&offset=0 (Caused by
> NewConnectionError(‘<urllib3.connection.VerirfiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 003EA0670>:Failed to established a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it’,))

Comment: How does it fail? What kind of virtual machine? Please provide more details. As it stands, it's impossible to figure out your problem

Comment: Hi,  sry for the delay
I use a windows virtual machine,
here is the error message :

Requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool<host=‘myserver‘,port=443>:Max retries exceeded with url: /URLpath.json?key=myAPIkey&limit=100&offset=0 (Caused by NewConnectionError(‘<urllib3.connection.VerirfiedHTTPSConnection object at 003EA0670>:Failed to established a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it’,))